# if/else control flow problems

Tags: if-statement

```
if (strcmp(buffer,"change work")==0)
{
   close(newsockfd);                   /*closing the old port*/
   close(sockfd);
   printf("Changing port to 51717....\n");
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (sockfd < 0)
   error("ERROR opening socket");
   bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
   portno = atoi("51717");
   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
   if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,  sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)     /*binding with the new port*/
   error("ERROR on binding");
   listen(sockfd,5);
   clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
   newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
   if (newsockfd < 0)
   error("ERROR on accept");
   printf("port changed\n");
   bzero(buffer,256);
   n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
   if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
   printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
   n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
   if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
  }
  else
  {
   printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
   n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
   if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
   close(newsockfd);
   close(sockfd);
  }
```

In the above code when the condition is satisfied, both the codes are being executed instead of code1. This loop is not working properly. what may be the reason???
I want to focus on if part.

Comment: Can you post *all* of the code?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this code behaves as you say. I suspect that your real code differs from what you show in some crucial respect.

Comment: May be, you don't have them braces around!

Comment: if he was just missing the braces then how would the the "else" compile?

Comment: **NB** title and tags changed as the question actually has nothing to do with sockets!

Comment: its executing just code2 only instead of code1.

Comment: Please explain the question fully in the text of the question. You now seem to be saying that the you only see the "else" portion of the code executing. In which case you need to focus on the strcmp().

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches to solving this:

a). Step in a debugger, you're quite likely to see that your code isn't quite as you think.

b). replace your complex code with a simple construct.

```
if (strcmp(buffer,"change work")!=0) 
   { printf("yes") } 
else 
   {  printf("no"); }
```

You will see that this works just fine, then make incremental changes to turn it back into your real code, at some point you'll go "aha".

Edited in light of your last comment:

My guess is that **buffer** does not contain exactly "change work" but perhaps also a newline character or other such delimiter. You would probably be benefit from adding diagnostic trace statements to show the buffer contents, use java.util.logging or log4j.

Comment: sorry iam doing in c language.

Comment: ah yes, but same principle, use some kind of diagnostic trace print statements.